# Multiple Prototype Cells - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble creating multiple prototype cells... Basically I need 2 static cells and 1 prototype cell that will add new rows based on the data input. Since you cannot create a static and prototype table I am trying to do this with 3 prototype cells. With the code below nothing displays in my table when run. It just shows a blank table.

Table View Controller:

```
class NewTableViewController: UITableViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var testData = [row1, row2, row3]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (section == 2){
        return testData.count
    }
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: CustomCell!

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!  CustomCell

        cell.myLabel.text = "Static Label"

    }else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.addLabel.text = "Add New Data"

    }else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("protoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.protoLabel.text = "row \(indexPath.row)"
    }

    return cell;
 }
}
```

CustomCell:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var addLabel: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var protoLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: Put some `println()`'s  where the cell text's are set to check if it's run.

Comment: Looks like it is not being run for some reason. I added the `println()`  as you stated and nothing shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you register you custom cell for use in viewDidLoad

```
var nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
```

You only have one custom cell as well, so you should only be using one reuse identifier in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I tried your solution above, however, I did not have any luck getting it to work. Additionally, I have 3 reuse identifiers because I am trying to create 3 different prototypes. Do I need to create 3 separate Custom Cells then? IE: CustomCell1, CustomCell2, CustomCell3.

Comment: if you want 3 different cells w/ different properties in each, then yes, you need to create 3 different custom cells like you stated. Each will have a different reuse identifier located in the attributes inspector (the side panel on the right, the same panel where you can change background color, font, etc...). You will then need to register each one like I showed above. Each will have a unique reuseIdentifier. Think of the reuseIdentifier as a unique name to distinguish each cell from the others. That's basically what it is.